# custom the function output to a specific format

Tags: python

I need your opinion on this problem,
I have an input like this:

```
input = 'user(1,2,15)'
```

and here I apply a function where I want this output like this:

```
def my_fucntion(input : str):
    if 'user' in input:
        print('i have four 4')
        output = 4
    else:
        print('i have three 3')
        output = 3 
    return ??
```

the ?? must be like this 'user(1,2,15, output)'

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: i need cast the output from 'user(1,2,15)' to output = 'user(1,2,15,4)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
return output.replace(")", f",{output})")
```

That will replace the closing parenthesis with ,{output})